# Chrome Extension - Saving just the text from a web element as a variable

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

The GitHub: https://github.com/TDev-Inquire/gsxintegration

I'm having trouble trying to make a chrome extension to copy certain web elements as a variable onto chrome storage and then dumping them into the respective places on the other website.
Name, address, phone number, etc. Basically a web scraper/paster.

I found a useful method and tried to redo it to work for me but now I'm stuck, pressing the secondary button only fills in the input box with "undefined"

**content_nomsg.js**

```
var cx_name = document.getElementById("custh1").value;


console.log("source page ran");

var storArray = {
    cx_name: "cxname",
   
    ///cx_problem: cxprblm,
    ///integ_id: intid
    };


chrome.storage.local.set({
        'newStorage': storArray
        });
```

**content2.js**

```
console.log("target content2 ran");

var storedLegal = chrome.storage.local.get('newStorage', function (items) {
    console.log(items); 

    document.querySelector("#home-search__textbox").value = items.newStorage.cxname;
    ///document.getElementById("lastName").value = items.newStorage.src_lname; 
  });
```

Thank you so much! Im really hoping I just missed something but I really am stuck.

Comment: Replace `"cxname"` with `cx_name`.

Comment: I did that, but when pasting the data it just fills the box in with "undefined",
I edited my post and put its GitHub at the top of it.

Comment: Replace `cxname` with `cx_name` in content2.js.